# Not showing Greek values in pdf

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am creating a pdf from a code and it is showing empty field for greek content.

```
$html.='<div class="example-application" >
            <h1 style="text-align:center;">Example</h1>
                    <h2 style="text-align:center;"><u>Example</u></h2>
                    <table>
        <tr>
        <td> Your Name: </td>
        <td>'. $example_details['example_name'] .' '. $example_details['example_surname'] .'
            </td>
        </tr>
        
    </table>';
        }
        $html.='</div>';
        $this->pdf->load_html($html);
        $this->pdf->render();

        $content = $this->pdf->output("Example_application-'.$example_application_id .'.pdf", 'S');
        $filename = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/assets/admin/files/uploads/example_applications/example_application-' . $example_application_id . '.pdf';
```

but if the value coming in name field is greek it is showing blank.what to do in this code to get its correct greek value.

Comment: Please install Greek fonts in your system and I think you should see the data if the rest of the other data is printing fine on pdf

Comment: fro where is  i should download it

Comment: any way to get it done through code

Answer (score 0):

You can find a few samples here: https://fonts.google.com/?subset=greek.
Once you have selected a font, then you can embed it in css

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  src: url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300&display=swap');
}
```

or

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

If you just want the Greek font to be effected, then you will need an identifier for the Greek language and then use it like the example below for specific classes. And if styling is not your concern right now then don't change your existing code. Just include the font as described above

```
// Fetch this programatically
$language = "greek";
$class = $language == "greek" ? "greek" : "other";

$html.='<div class="example-application" >
            <h1 style="text-align:center;">Example</h1>
                    <h2 style="text-align:center;"><u>Example</u></h2>
                    <table>
        <tr>
        <td> Your Name: </td>
        <td class="'.$class.'">'. $example_details['example_name'] .' '. $example_details['example_surname'] .'
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: does it affect english values

Comment: You can use separate css classes based on php code for different languages

Comment: can you given an example of it to be used

Comment: Edited my answer. Please check if that helps

Comment: actually this pdf is downloaded from a mail.this code is inaside a content.is thera any nedd to download any font.can you show how this can be included in the code above.i.e how to include font

Comment: This is not a view file.this is a controller file.how can i include the font here.

Comment: Add the font in your view file only. Rest of the code should be in the controller

Comment: what is this class="greek" mean.how to give style in view.just giving this one <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: please define all the characteristics of greek class in css file

Comment: can you given an example.i didn,t downloaded any fonts.i just pasted the code in controller and what to do in view file for getting greek value printed in my pdf

Comment: can you reply fastly.